# How to find which array key has value larger than 0

Tags: php

I have associative array in following way,

```
$data = array(
        'apple'=>0,
        'orange'=>5,
        'mango'=>0
    );
```

As you see `orange` is the only key has value larger than `0`. Assume `apple` has value larger than `0`.Then other values get `0`. If `mango` has value larger than `0`, then other values get `0`.

**I want to find which is the key has value larger than 0.**

I can write this following way but is there any easiest way to do that. Because assume if I have array with large number of element, I guess this is not a suitable way.

```
if(!empty($data['apple'])&&empty($data['orange'])&&empty($data['mango'])){
    // apple has value larger than 0
}else if(empty($data['apple'])&&!empty($data['orange'])&&empty($data['mango'])){
    // orange has value larger than 0
}else if(empty($data['apple'])&&empty($data['orange'])&&!empty($data['mango'])){
    // mango has value larger than 0
}
```

Thank you, someone please advice me.

Comment: You can use `array_keys(array_filter($data));` This will give you an array of keys having non-zero value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out empty values.

```
$fruit = key(array_filter($data));
```

`$fruit` will contain the value having a number greater than zero.

If more than one key has a value greater than zero, use `array_keys` instead of `key`

```
$fruit = array_keys(array_filter($data));
```

Comment: If `apple` and `orange` larger than `zero` then what will happen?

Comment: As per OP's attempt, only one key have a value greater than zero. Anyway, updated the answer to include that case

Comment: @jitendrapurohit This will fail for keys having multiple non-zero value. In such case it will return only the first key having non-zero value. It would be secure to use `array_keys(array_filter($data))`. It will give an array of keys having non-zero value.

Comment: OP's attempt(if....elseif....elseif) clearly says that it's array can only contain non zero value for only single key. Anyway, I've updated the answer if thats not the case.